# How to also run a change function on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, onchange

On a "create" page, I have a lot of stuff happening with checkboxes when one of them is either checked or unchecked, using...

```
$('.option').on('change', function() {
//lots of stuff
});
```

I have these checkboxes on an "edit" page as well, so when the "edit" page loads, it's setting all the checkboxes properly (check or unchecked), but there are also some math calculations done onchange that I need done on page load.  In other words, for the displayed numbers to be correct when the edit page is first opened, I need the "change" function above to run on page load.

Is that doable?    Basically want it to run on page load, and then again whenever there is an actual "change" (as originally intended).

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ may be this $(".option").trigger( "change" )

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the logic:

```
$('.option').on('change', function() {
   doLotOfStuff();
});

function doLotOfStuff() {
  // do your stuff here
}

$(document).ready(function loadPage() {
  doLotOfStuff();
});
```

This allows even to `extend` your logic (if required), and reuse it by passing different params on each case (again, if required).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `//lots of stuff` in a function. On event `ready` use the `one()` method to call your `//lots of stuff` only once. In this Snippet, I made a function called `process()` and it's called only once when DOM is `ready` and is called anytime a checkbox is under `change`.

**SNIPPET**

```js
/* When document is ready call on...
|...process() only once.
*/
$(document).one('ready', process);

// Any change on any checkbox call process()
$('.chx').on('change', process);

function process(e) {
  var total = 0;
  $(".chx:checked").each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
  });
  $('#total').val(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset>
  <label>1
    <input class='chx' type='checkbox' value='1'>
  </label>
  <label>2
    <input class='chx' type='checkbox' value='2'>
  </label>
  <label>3
    <input class='chx' type='checkbox' value='3'>
  </label>
  <label>4
    <input class='chx' type='checkbox' value='4' checked>
  </label>
  <label>5
    <input class='chx' type='checkbox' value='5'>
  </label>
  <label>6
    <input class='chx' type='checkbox' value='6'>
  </label>
  <label>7
    <input class='chx' type='checkbox' value='7' checked>
  </label>
  <label>8
    <input class='chx' type='checkbox' value='8'>
  </label>
  <label>9
    <input class='chx' type='checkbox' value='9'>
  </label>
  <label>10
    <input class='chx' type='checkbox' value='10' checked>
  </label>
</fieldset>
<label for='total'>Total:
  <output id='total'></output>
</label>
```